# How can I configure Ansible to manage Windows systems in multi realms?

Tags: windows, ansible, winrm

Fairly new to this....

I am currently managing windows systems in Domain1 with Ansible.

With minimal changes and be able to manage systems on another domain [domain2] in my workplace.

My current plan is

- Enable-PSremoting on Domain2 servers
- Then test winrm from Domain1\server1 to Domain2\server2 [firewall is open for WinRM]
- once successful test PS WinRM from Domain1\Ansible server to Domain2\servers
- configure & test multi realm ansible connectivity from Domain1\Ansible server to Domain2\servers
- Test playbook

  My question is what exactly is required for Ansible to connect to a second realm. I know I add settings for this into krb5.conf but not sure what else to do?

  Any help much appreciated

I have tried setting domain2 as both a secondary realm and then default realm in krb5.conf and tried to connect to domain2 systems but this locks me out

Is there a way to just add the second realm and then when I attempt connection ansible will attempt connection the the domain2 realm if domain1 fails?

....Hi not using MongoDB, just trying to run simple Ansible plays on an additional Domain. As per https://linux.die.net/man/5/krb5.conf
I have added an additional realm to krb5.conf

'''

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = DOMAIN1.COM

#default_tgs_enctypes = arcfour-hmac-md5 des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
#default_tkt_enctypes = arcfour-hmac-md5 des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
allow_weak_crypto = true
dns_lookup_realm = true
dns_lookup_kdc = true
#rdns = false

forward = true
forwardable = true
ticket_lifetime = 24h
renew_lifetime = 7d
dns_lookup_realm = false

[realms]
DOMAIN1.COM = {
kdc = DOMAIN1_DC.COM.COM
admin_server = DOMAIN1_DC.DOMAIN1.COM
default_domain = DOMAIN1.COM
kpasswd_server = DOMAIN1_DC.DOMAIN1.COM

DOMAIN2.COM = {
kdc = DOMAIN2_DC.COM.COM
admin_server = DOMAIN2_DC.DOMAIN2.COM
default_domain = DOMAIN2.COM
kpasswd_server = DOMAIN2_DC.DOMAIN2.COM
}

[domain_realm]
domain1.com = DOMAIN1.COM
.domain1.com = DOMAIN1.COM

domain2.com = DOMAIN2.COM
.domain2.com = DOMAIN2.COM

[logging]
default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmin.log
```

### '''

But this just locks me out

Comment: Can you clarify what Realm, part of MongoDB Realm, the database, has to do with this question? Do you have a code sample you're having difficulty with? Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ....Hi not using MongoDB, just trying to run simple Ansible plays on an additional Domain. As per https://linux.die.net/man/5/krb5.conf I have added an additional realm to krb5.conf. (above)